# Typescript error when using interface from module as field within class

Tags: module, typescript

I am working on providing a type definition file for fabric.js. The general structure is shown in the following sample:

```
declare module fabric {
   export interface Canvas {
      selectionBorderColor: string;
      selectionColor: string;
      ...
   }

   var Canvas: {
      new (): Canvas;
   }
}
```

This pattern allows me to use fabric.Canvas in a 'interface-like' way, so that variables are associated with the fabric.Canvas interface. At the same time it allows me to call "static members" (such as the constructor of fabric.Canvas).

But this leads to a problem when using a field of interface 'fabric.Canvas' within a class. The following sample shows such an case:

[image: Typescript error when using interface from module as field within class]

This problem only occurs when placing the interface within a module, otherwise everything works fine.

Any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some type confusion because you have an interface and a field with the same name - I know this is common in the `lib.d.ts` file, but I don't think it is a good practice when writing new TypeScript code. It seems to be something of a necessity for defining existing code.

If you rename `var Canvas` to `var MyCanvas` (or anything else) your code works.

I tend to prefix my interfaces with an `I`, for example `ICanvas` - but this isn't a TypeScript convention (yet).

```
declare module fabric {
   export class Canvas {
      selectionBorderColor: string;
      selectionColor: string;
   }
}

class MyClass {
    canvas: fabric.Canvas;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I am writing a type definition file for an existing JS library (Fabric.JS). So I need to support something like new fabric.Canvas as this is what the library needs (the library itself is not written in typescript)

Comment: If the implementation is in the existing JS library, you could change the `interface` keyword to `class`. The body of the declaration wouldn't need to change as it is in a module preceded by the `declare` keyword. I have updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Using a different name for the interface now seems to work. In my case I now use ICanvas for the interface and Canvas for the declaration (so that new fabric.Canvas still works).